# increasing the PPA limitation of a design

Tags: vhdl, asic

i finished creating a design in vhdl, of the algorithm sha256.
now im trying to get my design level higher by understanding how to change the code so i will get higher result of power, performance and area. the end game goal is trying to get the best netlist in my designs so i can get them into a chip.

so for my design: i got max frequency of 85 mhz in cyclone 4 FPGA with the usage of 8,500 total logic elements, 55% of the FPGA.

the main issue that i think made my design so big is that i wrote the code in a hierarchy manner, a lot of "elsif" and variables. and one other thing that could be better, i think, is if the quartus would implement my memory design as a memory and not with logic element, even that its only array of 16 words of 32 bits.
what you guys think i can improve ?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

entity padding is
port(       clk     :   in      std_logic;
            rst     :   in      std_logic;
            ward    :   in      std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
            ready   :   out     std_logic;
            hash    :   out     std_logic_vector(255 downto 0));
end;

architecture padding of padding is

component sha256 
    port (      clk         :  in   std_logic;
                rst         :  in   std_logic;
                enable      :  in   std_logic;
                ward            :  in   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                k               :  in   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                h0              :  in   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                h1              :  in   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                h2              :  in   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                h3              :  in   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                h4              :  in   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                h5              :  in   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                h6              :  in   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                h7              :  in   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                ready           :  out  std_logic;
                digest      :  out  std_logic_vector(255 downto 0));
end component;

type kconst is array ( 0 to 63 ) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
type mem    is array ( 0 to 15 ) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

signal k                : kconst := (x"428a2f98", x"71374491", x"b5c0fbcf", x"e9b5dba5", x"3956c25b", x"59f111f1", x"923f82a4", x"ab1c5ed5",
                                             x"d807aa98", x"12835b01", x"243185be", x"550c7dc3", x"72be5d74", x"80deb1fe", x"9bdc06a7", x"c19bf174",
                                             x"e49b69c1", x"efbe4786", x"0fc19dc6", x"240ca1cc", x"2de92c6f", x"4a7484aa", x"5cb0a9dc", x"76f988da",
                                             x"983e5152", x"a831c66d", x"b00327c8", x"bf597fc7", x"c6e00bf3", x"d5a79147", x"06ca6351", x"14292967",
                                             x"27b70a85", x"2e1b2138", x"4d2c6dfc", x"53380d13", x"650a7354", x"766a0abb", x"81c2c92e", x"92722c85",
                                             x"a2bfe8a1", x"a81a664b", x"c24b8b70", x"c76c51a3", x"d192e819", x"d6990624", x"f40e3585", x"106aa070",
                                             x"19a4c116", x"1e376c08", x"2748774c", x"34b0bcb5", x"391c0cb3", x"4ed8aa4a", x"5b9cca4f", x"682e6ff3",
                                             x"748f82ee", x"78a5636f", x"84c87814", x"8cc70208", x"90befffa", x"a4506ceb", x"bef9a3f7", x"c67178f2");

signal first_mem        : mem:= (   x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000",
                                    x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000"); 

signal second_mem       : mem:= (   x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"80000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000",
                                    x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000000", x"00000280");

signal enable           : std_logic;
signal enable1          : std_logic;
signal enable2          : std_logic;
signal r_d              : std_logic;
signal k_in             : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal ward_in          : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal ward_in1         : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal ward_in2         : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal h0,h1,h2,h3  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal h4,h5,h6,h7  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

signal temp             : std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);
signal temp1            : std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);
signal gama0            : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal gama1            : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal gama2            : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal gama3            : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal gama4            : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal gama5            : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin

sha1: sha256 port map(  
                clk         ,
                rst         ,
                enable      ,
                ward_in     ,
                k_in            ,
                h0              ,
                h1              ,
                h2              ,
                h3              ,
                h4              ,
                h5              ,
                h6              ,
                h7              ,
                enable1         ,
                temp            );
sha2: sha256 port map(  
                clk         ,
                rst         ,
                enable1     ,
                ward_in1        ,
                k_in            ,
                temp(255 downto 224),
                temp(223 downto 192),
                temp(191 downto 160),
                temp(159 downto 128),
                temp(127 downto 96 ),
                temp(95 downto 64  ),
                temp(63 downto 32  ),
                temp(31 downto 0   ),
                enable2         ,
                temp1           );
sha3: sha256 port map(  
                clk         ,
                rst         ,
                r_d         ,
                ward_in2        ,
                k_in            ,
                h0              ,
                h1              ,
                h2              ,
                h3              ,
                h4              ,
                h5              ,
                h6              ,
                h7              ,
                ready           ,
                hash            );

h0  <= x"6a09e667";
h1  <= x"bb67ae85";
h2  <= x"3c6ef372";
h3  <= x"a54ff53a";
h4  <= x"510e527f";
h5  <= x"9b05688c";
h6  <= x"1f83d9ab";
h7  <= x"5be0cd19";             

process (clk,rst)
variable i : integer;
variable j : integer;
variable m : integer;
variable n : integer;
variable l : integer;
begin
    if rst = '0' then
        enable      <= '0';
        i := 0;
        j := 0;
        m := 9;
        n := 15;
        l := 8; 
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
        if j = 16 then
           j := 0;
        end if;
        if m = 16 then
           m := 0;
        end if;
        if n = 16 then
           n := 0;
        end if;
        if l = 16 then
           l := 0;
        end if;
        if i  = 193 then
           i := 0;
        elsif i  > 144  then
            first_mem(n) <= gama4 + first_mem(l) + gama5 + first_mem(n);
            ward_in2     <= gama4 + first_mem(l) + gama5 + first_mem(n);
            k_in         <= k(i-129);
        elsif i  > 136 then
            ward_in2           <= first_mem(n);
            k_in             <= k(i-129);  
        elsif i  = 136 then
            first_mem(n)   <= temp1(31 downto 0);
            ward_in2           <= temp1(31 downto 0);
            k_in             <= k(i-129);
        elsif i  = 135 then
            first_mem(n)   <= temp1(63 downto 32);
            ward_in2           <= temp1(63 downto 32);
            k_in             <= k(i-129);
        elsif i  = 134 then
            first_mem(n)   <= temp1(95 downto 64);
            ward_in2           <= temp1(95 downto 64);
            k_in             <= k(i-129);
        elsif i  = 133 then
            first_mem(n)   <= temp1(127 downto 96);
            ward_in2           <= temp1(127 downto 96);
            k_in             <= k(i-129);
        elsif i  = 132 then
            first_mem(n)   <= temp1(159 downto 128);
            ward_in2           <= temp1(159 downto 128);
            k_in             <= k(i-129);
        elsif i  = 131 then
            first_mem(n)   <= temp1(191 downto 160);
            ward_in2           <= temp1(191 downto 160);
            k_in             <= k(i-129);
        elsif i  = 130 then
            first_mem(n)   <= temp1(223 downto 192);
            ward_in2           <= temp1(223 downto 192);
            k_in             <= k(i-129);
        elsif i  = 129 then
            first_mem(15) <= x"00000100";
            first_mem(14) <= x"00000000";
            first_mem(13) <= x"00000000";
            first_mem(12) <= x"00000000";
            first_mem(11) <= x"00000000";
            first_mem(10) <= x"00000000";
            first_mem(9) <= x"00000000";
            first_mem(8) <= x"80000000";
            first_mem(n) <= temp1(255 downto 224);
            ward_in2         <= temp1(255 downto 224);
            k_in             <= k(i-129);
        elsif i  = 128 then 
        elsif i  > 79  then
            second_mem(j) <= gama2 + second_mem(m) + gama3 + second_mem(j);
            ward_in1      <= gama2 + second_mem(m) + gama3 + second_mem(j);
            k_in          <= k(i-64);       
        elsif i  > 63  then
            enable       <= '0';
            ward_in1         <= second_mem(j);
            k_in         <= k(i-64);
        elsif i  > 19  then
            first_mem(j) <= gama0 + first_mem(m) + gama1 + first_mem(j);
            ward_in      <= gama0 + first_mem(m) + gama1 + first_mem(j);
            k_in         <= k(i);
            enable      <= '1';
        elsif i  > 15  then
            second_mem(j)<= ward;
            first_mem(j) <= gama0 + first_mem(m) + gama1 + first_mem(j);
            ward_in      <= gama0 + first_mem(m) + gama1 + first_mem(j);
            k_in         <= k(i);   
            enable      <= '1';
        elsif i  >= 0   then
            first_mem(i) <= ward;
            ward_in      <= ward;
            k_in         <= k(i);
            enable      <= '1';
        end if;
        i := i + 1;
        j := j + 1;
        m := m + 1;
        n := n + 1;
        l := l + 1;
    end if;
end process;

process (clk, rst)
begin
    if rst = '0' then
        r_d <= '0';
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
        r_d <= enable2;
    end if;
end process;

process (clk, rst)
variable f: integer;
variable j: integer;
variable l: integer;
variable m: integer;
begin
    if rst = '0' then
        f := 2;
        j := 15;
        l := 1;
        m := 14;
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
        if j = 16 then
            j := 0;
        end if;
        if f = 16 then
            f := 0;
        end if;
        if l = 16 then
            l := 0;
        end if;
        if m = 16 then
            m := 0;
        end if;
        gama0 <= ((first_mem(f)(6 downto 0) & first_mem(f)(31 downto 7)) xor (first_mem(f)(17 downto 0) & first_mem(f)(31 downto 18)) xor ("000" & first_mem(f)(31 downto 3)));
        gama1 <= ((first_mem(j)(16 downto 0) & first_mem(j)(31 downto 17)) xor (first_mem(j)(18 downto 0) & first_mem(j)(31 downto 19)) xor ("0000000000" & first_mem(j)(31 downto 10)));
        gama4 <= ((first_mem(l)(6 downto 0) & first_mem(l)(31 downto 7)) xor (first_mem(l)(17 downto 0) & first_mem(l)(31 downto 18)) xor ("000" & first_mem(l)(31 downto 3)));
        gama5 <= ((first_mem(m)(16 downto 0) & first_mem(m)(31 downto 17)) xor (first_mem(m)(18 downto 0) & first_mem(m)(31 downto 19)) xor ("0000000000" & first_mem(m)(31 downto 10)));
        gama2 <= ((second_mem(f)(6 downto 0) & second_mem(f)(31 downto 7)) xor (second_mem(f)(17 downto 0) & second_mem(f)(31 downto 18)) xor ("000" & second_mem(f)(31 downto 3)));
        gama3 <= ((second_mem(j)(16 downto 0) & second_mem(j)(31 downto 17)) xor (second_mem(j)(18 downto 0) & second_mem(j)(31 downto 19)) xor ("0000000000" & second_mem(j)(31 downto 10)));
        f := f + 1;
        j := j + 1;
        l := l + 1;
        m := m + 1;
    end if;
end process;

end;
```

Comment: First: this is not a [mcve]. We are missing a lot of declarations. If you want a code review, you should supply all the code. Secondly, you are using variables for clocked statements: that's bad design for implementation. You should only use variables for temporary in-process calculations. Everything that spans over multiple process entries should be a signal. Your design can also be big because you are not using RAM: because you are accessing multiple values in `first_mem` at the same time, it is implemented using registers. Read the Altera synthesis manual for coding guidelines.

Comment: It also seems that you are using variable `i` as one big combined state-machine and logic selector, which leads to weird constructs like `k_in <= k(i-129);`. Don't do that. Design a normal state machine (google VHDL fsm examples) and internally use a separate counter for timing and element selection.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, i edit with full code. and i will go over my design and try to change according to ur inputs.

Comment: I'm sorry that I am not able to elaborate on my feedback. I have a deadline and there's just too much to comment on. One thing about RAMs: if you want to use RAM, you need not only to remember it only has 1 or 2 ports which you can use at the same time, but also that it takes an additional clock cycle to get the data. So for `first_mem(n) <= gama4 + first_mem(l) + gama5 + first_mem(n);` you need one cycle to get `first_mem(n)` and one clock cycle to write `first_mem(n)`... And you probably also need 1-2 clock cycles to perform the addition. By clever design it is often possible to anticipate .

Comment: @JHBonarius The problem with this question is that it is subjective. You say "you are using variables for clocked statements: that's bad design for implementation." I disagree.

Comment: @JHBonarius i gave it 16 cycles to read, so i do not think there should be an issue in it, but i tried to understand why he implement register and not ram, according to what you said "accessing multiple values in first_mem" the only time i do that is in i =129 and that to load the ram. but he didn't implement the second_mem as ram and i didn't access multiple values there.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor i used the variable in order to  wrote the code easier, i hoped it won't made issue, but the design is very big, how would you do this ?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor OK, it is not a fixed truth. I made my statement for the general case where people with a software background new to VHDL tend to use variables where they should use signals (in the case of synthesizable logic). Some synthesis tools will screw-up if you do so (at least, they did in the past). Alas, I cannot edit my comment.

Comment: P.s. [here](https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/vhdl/vhd-true-dual-port-ram-sclk.html) is an example of a True dual-port block-RAM.

Comment: @shmulikm I've been analyzing your code, and if will be very difficult to get it to use block-RAM: You just want to do too many things at the same time. As I said: `first_mem(n) <= gama4 + first_mem(l) + gama5 + first_mem(n);` will already take 3 clock cycles when pipelined and using block-RAM. But then the second process is also accessing the first_mem at the same time! Furthermore, the code is not really written in a maintainable way, so it's difficult to know what is happening everywhere. I think you need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @JHBonarius oh, i understand what you mean now, since i need the data at the same time (same clock) i can't use ram (i guess i can i just need to invest in some process and registers in pipeline architecture). well right now the code work fine,its just slow and big, so i will not change the part of the memory, and try to focus on the if part, i do not see how using fsm will make my design better, moore will be probably same size (?) and mealy will be complicated in my design no ?

Comment: @user1155120 yes, its result was validated. the code do what is supposed to do.
the PPA mean power, preference and area. 
im asking for the asic help since i want to get improvment in the implementation of my RTL in preparation of asic design, the FPGA should be only a prototype before chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elsif, i.e. "priority en/decoding", will effect the frequency of your design.  With all the available logic resources you have left, you might consider a case statement... unless you actually have a need for priority en/decoding.  Even then, if you can afford latency trade-offs you can do the decoding in several clock cycles (pipeline the decode) and your design will likely increase frequency...  ultimately, you need to run a timing report and look at the slow paths to understand the bottlenecks.

If you really want to use RAM instead of FFs, you could infer a RAM (create an array), or if that doesn't work for you, you could then manually instantiate a device-specific RAM.... and, then, of course, add the control logic for it.  if primitive, blackbox it to swap later for "same" ASIC library primitive

As far as "variables", the discussion is the same as "VHDL" vs. "Verilog", or "synch" vs "asynch" resets, mostly just opinions, and mine is, "I am not a fan of variables in synthesizable RTL"... they are legal for synthesis, but they "disappear" during syn, so that if you ever want to look at a netlist and compare to your RTL, you get to manually trace the connections.  There is usually not a good reason to have variables, as they represent nothing in terms of Hardware, and obfuscate the design vs. netlist.  I like to see logic types of wire/net/regs, so that it is clear what you are creating in HW.  But, as you please, i just tend to cringe when i see them.

Along the same lines, in terms of arrays, I am not a big fan of "bundling signals into arrays"... folks will argue it is "faster" and "easier" to deal with, but to me, it further obfuscates the design.  Again, not illegal, but when it comes to OPC (Other people's code) it can be very annoying trying to trace signals, not only within a module, but, arrays across ports too... and then, if they slice those arrays, or decimate them otherwise, it gets even more annoying.  Kind of like this rant :)

Ultimately, you can do whatever you want, and especially in an FPGA, some folks tend to be less attention-to-detail about what will be created versus an ASIC.  If you are designing an ASIC, I would say you should err on the side of being more pedantic and be able to look at your RTL and know what (to some extent) is going to be created and as such be able to estimate the gate count if you need.  To this end, I highly recommend taking the time to draw your design in a drawing program (e.g. visio) to include gates, FFs, decoders, Muxes, FSMs, pseudo-code where appropriate, details of your clock and reset trees, and all CDC crossing logic, etc., including signal names.  Once you have that, it is just a matter of translating to RTL... likely, too, as a bonus for those that share my opinion on variables, you will find no variables in your drawing and thus none in your RTL. :)

Comment: wow that was amazing! thanks, i will try to do what you said.
usually i do see in my mind the RTL before i code, but since im new to big ICs the RTL in my mind miss a lot.

Comment: Well, I kind of digressed, as it was more of a "how to approach an IC design" in general terms, but, I am happy you got something from it.